# How to add another column returned for complicated MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a rather complicated MySQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pe.first, ' ', pe.last) AS Name,
                   tp.EmpID as 'Empl ID',
                   DATE_FORMAT(tp.PunchDateTime, '%m-%d-%Y') AS 'Punch Date',
                   DATE_FORMAT(tp.PunchDateTime, '%W') AS 'Weekday',
                   TRUNCATE((SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(PunchDateTime) * (1 - 2 * `In-Out`)) / 3600),2)
                      AS 'Hours Worked'
              FROM timeclock_punchlog tp LEFT JOIN prempl01 pe ON tp.EmpID = pe.prempl
             WHERE tp.PunchDateTime >= '2013-06-16' and tp.PunchDateTime < '2013-06-23'
             AND tp.EmpID = 1588
            GROUP BY date(PunchDateTime), EmpID
            ORDER BY Name, `Punch Date` ASC
```

Now I need to add a 6th column.  I need to know how long the employee's lunch was.  I think it's going to involve a subquery in the select section, because it would be too complicated to get it any other way.  Calculating the 'Hours Worked' was complicated because I needed to calculate the (breakout - clockin) + (clockout - breakin) for each day.  Now I need to calculate breakin - breakout for each of those days as well.  Here is the structure for the current table for one employee for one day.

```
PunchID EmpID   PunchEvent    PunchDateTime           In-Out
308     1588    clockin       6/17/2013 6:20:48 AM    Checked
313     1588    breakout      6/17/2013 12:15:18 PM   Unchecked
315     1588    breakin       6/17/2013 12:43:58 PM   Checked
319     1588    clockout      6/17/2013 5:00:37 PM    Unchecked
```

I can't figure out how I would add the lunch break time to the above query. Hopefully I have provided all the information needed.

**Update:** I have put together a working query that does what I want for a specific day and specific employee.  Now what I need is for this query to work for all employees for a specific date range(ie week).  Here is the query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pe.first, ' ', pe.last) AS Name,
   tp.EmpID AS 'Empl ID',
   DATE_FORMAT(tp.PunchDateTime, '%m-%d-%Y') AS 'Punch Date',
   DATE_FORMAT(tp.PunchDateTime, '%W') AS 'Weekday',
   TRUNCATE((SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(PunchDateTime) * (1 - 2 * `In-Out`)) / 3600), 2)
      AS 'Hours Worked',
   (SELECT TIMEDIFF
 ((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tpl.PunchDateTime, '%r') as dTime FROM timeclock_punchlog tpl WHERE tpl.PunchEvent = 'breakin' AND tpl.EmpID = 1588 AND DATE(tpl.PunchDateTime) = '2013-06-17'),
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tpl.PunchDateTime, '%r') as dTime FROM timeclock_punchlog tpl WHERE tpl.PunchEvent = 'breakout' AND tpl.EmpID = 1588 AND DATE(tpl.PunchDateTime) = '2013-06-17'))) as 'Lunch'
                      FROM timeclock_punchlog tp LEFT JOIN prempl01 pe ON tp.EmpID = pe.prempl
                     WHERE DATE(tp.PunchDateTime) = '2013-06-17'
                     AND tp.EmpID = 1588
                    GROUP BY date(PunchDateTime), EmpID
                    ORDER BY Name, `Punch Date` ASC
```

And the result:

```
Name            Empl ID Punch Date  Weekday Hours Worked    Lunch
BRUCE COLEMAN   1588    06-17-2013  Monday  10.18           00:28:40
```

Now if someone can figure out how to make that query work without specifying the employee ID and without specifying an exact date, make it a date range instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace both `tpl.EmpID = 1588` with `tpl.EmpID = tp.EmpID` and remove the `AND tp.EmpID = 1588`.

**Edit:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(pe.first, ' ', pe.last) AS Name,
       tp.EmpID AS 'Empl ID',
       DATE_FORMAT(tp.PunchDateTime, '%m-%d-%Y') AS 'Punch Date',
       DATE_FORMAT(tp.PunchDateTime, '%W') AS 'Weekday',
       TRUNCATE((SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(PunchDateTime) * (1 - 2 * `In-Out`)) / 3600), 2) AS 'Hours Worked',
       (SELECT TIMEDIFF((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tpl.PunchDateTime, '%r') as dTime FROM timeclock_punchlog tpl WHERE tpl.PunchEvent = 'breakin' AND tpl.EmpID = tp.EmpID AND DATE(tpl.PunchDateTime) = '2013-06-17'),
                        (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tpl.PunchDateTime, '%r') as dTime FROM timeclock_punchlog tpl WHERE tpl.PunchEvent = 'breakout' AND tpl.EmpID = tp.EmpID AND DATE(tpl.PunchDateTime) = '2013-06-17'))) as 'Lunch'
FROM timeclock_punchlog tp LEFT JOIN prempl01 pe ON tp.EmpID = pe.prempl
WHERE DATE(tp.PunchDateTime) = '2013-06-17'
GROUP BY date(PunchDateTime), EmpID
ORDER BY Name, `Punch Date` ASC
```

Comment: That is genius.  Using that info I figured out I just had to add WHERE conditions of "DATE(tpl.PunchDateTime) = DATE(tp.PunchDateTime)" to make the dates dynamic as well.  Thank you!